# Last remaining number

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

I was asked this question in an interview.

Given an array 'arr' of positive integers and a starting index 'k' of the array. Delete element at k and jump arr[k] steps in the array in circular fashion. Do this repeatedly until only one element remain. Find the last remaining element.

I thought of O(nlogn) solution using ordered map. Is any O(n) solution possible?

Comment: Does index of elements change after deletion?

Comment: Yes, index changes after deletion.

Comment: I think with a pen and paper and a bit thinking you can find a O(1) solution.

Comment: I thought and gave a lot of time to this problem. It is quite similar to Josephus problem. But i am not able to find a similar solution to this problem.

Comment: @Sumit Kumar to me it looks exactly like the Josephus problem. Why do you think it is different?

Comment: In josephus problem, the length of jumping was constant. Here it depends upon which array index we are currently at. Since indexes change as we delete elements, it is difficult to get array elements with deletion.

Comment: also I thought the josephus problem is only known to have constant time solutions for step sizes of 2 or 3. For the general case, the solution takes O(n).

Comment: The description of the general case of the Josephus problem says, "Dynamic programming is used to solve this problem in the general case by performing the first step and then using the solution of the remaining problem." The only difference in your case is that in "the remaining problem," `k` changes. That shouldn't pose an issue, since essentially what you're doing is just performing the first step of the problem, with 1 fewer item and a different `k`. You should be able to use the standard dynamic programming solution with a slight modification.

Comment: @MrSmith42 I don't see how we can have an `O(1)` procedure here, when the question depends on specific elements in an input of arbitrary size `n`.

Comment: @JimMischel could you please provide some working code or a recurrence? I can't seem to make your idea work.

Comment: @גלעדברקן If I had working code or a recurrence, I would have posted an answer. I based my comment on a reading of the Wikipedia article. It's the first approach I would take.

Comment: I dont understand the DP approach either. I can see how to do it in O(n log n). Basically the key thing is that the naive approach, just doing it in the straightforward way is O(n^2) because just deleting one item from an array is O(n). if you follow the chain to the end you do O(n) deletes; the whole thing would be O(n^2).

Comment: To do the same thing but faster you would need a data structure that maintains which items were deleted and can convert an index from the array with deleted items back to the original array faster than by actually doing deletes on the array. I can see how this could be done with a binary tree of ranges of non-deleted items. Lookup in that would be log(n) so the running time of the whole algorithm would O(n log n). I dont see how an O(n) solution could work.

Comment: because in the Josephus problem you literally do not have to look at the array. The step size is fixed. In this case it is dependent on the values of the array. By that fact alone you can see that there cannot be a better solution than O(n).

Comment: oh right ... yeah I agree.

Comment: O(nlogn) is already challenging. I don't see how an ordered set would help, you could have duplicates in the array. Also a binary tree where you store how many elements are deleted in a segment wouldn't help. Yes, you could look up how many deletions are there up to the calculated position, but then you would have to add the deletions to the index and look again if there were any deletions in that segment and so on. Similarly for segments with undeleted items.

Comment: @SumitKumar how did you use an ordered set to solve it in O(n log n)? Wouldn't looking up the next index to remove be O(n) for each lookup?

Comment: I actually meant ordered map instead of ordered set. Pardon for my mistake. We can make an augmented ordered map(Balanced BST) with subtree sizes in each node. At first, indices of the array are used as keys and array elements as values to make the BST. Whenever we want to search for a particular index we will use subtree sizes as illustrated in גלעד ברקן's answer. Whenever we delete any element we will update subtree sizes of related nodes. That way we can have O(logn) deletion and search. So the whole algorithm will be O(nlogn).

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that there is not an `O(n)` solution to this problem based on the fact that it seems to involve doing something that is impossible. The obvious thing you would need to solve this problem in linear time is a data structure like an array that exposes two operations on an ordered collection of values:

1. `O(1)` order-preserving deletes from the data structure.
2. `O(1)` lookups of the nth undeleted item in the data structure.

However, such a data structure has been formally proven to not exist; see "[Optimal Algorithms for List Indexing and Subset Rank](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.627.6526)" and its citations. It is not a proof to say that if the natural way to solve some problem involves using a data structure that is impossible, the problem itself is probably impossible, but such an intuition is often correct.

Anyway there are lots of ways to do this in `O(n log n)`. Below is an implementation of maintaining a tree of undeleted ranges in the array. `GetIndex()` below returns an index into the original array given a zero-based index into the array if items had been deleted from it. Such a tree is not self-balancing so will have `O(n)` operations in the worst case but in the average case `Delete` and `GetIndex` will be `O(log n)`.

```
namespace CircleGame
{
    class Program
    {
        class ArrayDeletes
        {
            private class UndeletedRange
            {
                private int _size;
                private int _index;
                private UndeletedRange _left;
                private UndeletedRange _right;

                public UndeletedRange(int i, int sz)
                {
                    _index = i;
                    _size = sz;
                }

                public bool IsLeaf()
                {
                    return _left == null && _right == null;
                }

                public int Size()
                {
                    return _size;
                }

                public void Delete(int i)
                {
                    if (i >= _size)
                        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

                    if (! IsLeaf())
                    {
                        int left_range = _left._size;
                        if (i < left_range)
                            _left.Delete(i);
                        else
                            _right.Delete(i - left_range);
                        _size--;
                        return;
                    }

                    if (i == _size - 1)
                    {
                        _size--; // Can delete the last item in a range by decremnting its size
                        return;
                    }

                    if (i == 0)  // Can delete the first item in a range by incrementing the index
                    {  
                        _index++;
                        _size--;
                        return;
                    }

                    _left = new UndeletedRange(_index, i);
                    int right_index = i + 1;
                    _right = new UndeletedRange(_index + right_index, _size - right_index);
                    _size--;
                    _index = -1; // the index field of a non-leaf is no longer necessarily valid.
                }

                public int GetIndex(int i)
                {
                    if (i >= _size)
                        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

                    if (IsLeaf())
                        return _index + i;

                    int left_range = _left._size;
                    if (i < left_range)
                        return _left.GetIndex(i);
                    else
                        return _right.GetIndex(i - left_range);
                }

            }

            private UndeletedRange _root;

            public ArrayDeletes(int n)
            {
                _root = new UndeletedRange(0, n);
            }

            public void Delete(int i)
            {
                _root.Delete(i);
            }

            public int GetIndex(int indexRelativeToDeletes )
            {
                return _root.GetIndex(indexRelativeToDeletes);
            }

            public int Size()
            {
                return _root.Size();
            }
        }

        static int CircleGame( int[] array, int k )
        {
            var ary_deletes = new ArrayDeletes(array.Length);
            while (ary_deletes.Size() > 1)
            {
                int next_step = array[ary_deletes.GetIndex(k)];
                ary_deletes.Delete(k);
                k = (k + next_step - 1) % ary_deletes.Size();
            }
            return array[ary_deletes.GetIndex(0)];
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var array = new int[] { 5,4,3,2,1 };
            int last_remaining = CircleGame(array, 2); // third element, this call is zero-based...
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that if the values in the array are known to be bounded such that they are always less than some m less than n, there are lots of `O(nm)` algorithms -- for example, just using a circular linked list.

Comment: Your last observation using circular linked list is awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't think of an `O(n)` solution. However, we could have `O(n log n)` average time by using a treap or an augmented BST with a value in each node for the size of its subtree. The treap enables us to find and remove the `k`th entry in `O(log n)` average time.

For example, `A = [1, 2, 3, 4]` and `k = 3` (as Sumit reminded me in the comments, use the array indexes as values in the tree since those are ordered):

```
          2(0.9)
         /     \
      1(0.81)   4(0.82)
               /
              3(0.76)
```

Find and remove 3rd element. Start at 2 with size = 2 (including the left subtree). Go right. Left subtree is size 1, which together makes 3, so we found the 3rd element. Remove:

```
          2(0.9)
         /     \
      1(0.81)   4(0.82)
```

Now we're starting on the third element in an array with `n - 1 = 3` elements and looking for the 3rd element from there. We'll use zero-indexing to correlate with our modular arithmetic, so the third element in modulus 3 would be 2 and `2 + 3 = 5 mod 3 = 2`, the second element. We find it immediately since the root with its left subtree is size 2. Remove:

```
          4(0.82)
         /
      1(0.81)
```

Now we're starting on the second element in modulus 2, so 1, and we're adding 2. 3 mod 2 is 1. Removing the first element we are left with 4 as the last element.

Comment: @SumitKumar yes, of course. We will use the array indexes as values in the tree.